# Translation of a Nietzsche-related text; OK?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

In [an answer of mine on *Philosophy*](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/6533/3164), I (neither native-German nor native-English speaking) translated some German to English as follows.

> Nachdem man nun weiß, was die Zukunft von Ehe und Gattin sein soll, versteht man auch, was die „kleine Wahrheit“ des „alten Weibleins“ bedeutet. „Die Peitsche dient anscheinend dazu, die eigenen sinnlichen Begierden bei der Wahl und im Umgang mit einer Gattin im Zaume zu halten, damit sie nicht als entscheidender Gesichtspunkt vorherrschen, sondern dass die Hervorbringung des Übermenschen dabei im Mittelpunkt steht.“

[*Original*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Also_sprach_Zarathustra#Von_alten_und_jungen_Weiblein)

> After one now knows what the future of marriage and wife should be, one also understands what the "small truth" of the "little old woman" means. "The whip is apparently to keep in check one's own sensual desires in choosing and dealing with a wife, so that these desires don't form a dominating perspective, but rather that the creation of [*Übermenschen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbermensch) is central."

*My translation*

Is this OK? Can it be improved upon (without adding interpretation)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to translate the text on my own. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to completely dismiss your translation out of my head. Additionally, I'm not very good in interpretation so perhaps I missed an essential connotation in the original. For example I was thinking of *intercourse* instead of *interaction* (respectively *dealing* in your translation) but then I thought this word-choice would be too prominent, maybe even obtrusive. (Note that this word has an old-fashioned meaning which is restricted to *communications or dealings between individuals or groups* ([Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intercourse?q=intercourse)))

> After knowing what the future of marriage and wife should be, you also understand what the "little truth" of the "little old woman" means. "The whip apparently serves to keep in check the sensual desires in the choice of and in the interaction with a wife in order not to allow them to be a dominant aspect but that the creation of the Übermensch occupies the center."